# One class and nested elements in CSS

Tags: html, css, angular

I am kind of new to CSS. I have css that applied to table->td and table->td->input separately like below in the local file but i am moving these two styles to global css files. So i want this style to be applied to all the table available in the project and also i don't want to create two separate classes and apply it instead i want to create one class, inside that class apply styles for both table=>td and table->td->input.  Is there any way to combine these two into one.

What i have currently is,

```
table td {
...
}

table td input {
..
..
}
```

### Expecting something like this.

### CSS:

```
.someclassname {
   table td 
   { 
      ....
   }
   table td input 
   {
      ....
   }
}
```

### HTML:

```
<table class="someclassname">
..
</table>
```

Please guide if there is any way to implement in css.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use nested CSS then you have to take a look to the preprocessing / precompiled  CSS like **SCSS**.

CSS preprocessors compile the code written with a special compiler. A valid CSS file would be created, which you can include to your page.

https://sass-lang.com/guide